# .Net Core WebAPI Services confusion : accessing a singleton throughout application

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-webapi

I seem to be confusing myself and would like to get this straight.

I have a .net 6.0 WebAPI where in my Program.cs i have gone about defining my `builder.Services`, I have also defined my http controller and routes, using the controller - repository methodology, which all works fine, these utilize Mongo via DI and that also works fine.

***I want to use this Mongo service in other areas of code outside of the repositories*** which use DI and work fine.

**Here is my Program.cs (relevant code only):**

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(options => {
    var settings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MongoDBSettings").Get<MongoDBSettings>();
    var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
    return client;
});
```

How can I access this Mongo client from anywhere?

Here is how i'm doing it in the controller repository methodology but this seems like overkill to structure up if I just want to connect to my Mongo instance in a general function somewhere.

**Typical Repository:**

```
namespace vWebAPI.Repository
{
    public class vRepository : IvRepository
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<vMsg_Rec> _vCollection;

        public vRepository(IMongoClient mongoClient)
        {
            IMongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase("v_mdb01");

            _vCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<vMsg_Rec>("v");
        }
```

Comment: Are you talking about `IMongoDatabase` or `IMongoClient` ?

Comment: I would like to access the `IMongoClient` created in `Program.cs` as a service anywhere throughout my application in ancillary code/classes, not the repository method used for my http routes/controller

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try to access `IMongoClient` from anywhere?

Comment: @beautifulcoder yes it is not visible from any class where i have not gone through inheriting it via the repository methodology.  I would like to have it visible in any class. TY

Comment: I'd be curious to see how you are setting up your consumer classes in the IoC container. My guess is there is a misconfiguration somewhere.